# Hide mobile safari keyboard while using bluetooth keyboard.

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, ipad

I am using a bluetooth keyboard to input things on a form in safari, however... how do I hide the keyboard while the bluetooth one is connected... it doesn't make sense to have both keyboards open.

I have access to change the html of the website that I need to do this to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyy, as far as I know, mobile safari keyboards are displayed always. Therefore the Bluetooth keyboard will be shown as well as the default one. You would only be able to hide the keyboard by altering the software. However, it could be possible with a jailbreak tweak; only if your prepared to do that though.

-InfiniDaZa

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard show function is invoked every time you start entering a form field. This is something that you cant change unless you alter the software.

Answer (score 0):

I tested on iOS 6.0 on ipad. there is no such issue. the keyboard is not displayed when click on a form, such as sign in google. It only shows a bar at the bottom.